# Adding common buttons to each GWT view

Tags: gwt

My GWT app will have 4 - 5 different views but each one will have 2 similar buttons on the bottom of the view. The function of these buttons will vary between each view but their appeararnce/position will remain the same.  Is there any design strategy that I could apply in this case? Could I go down the road of having a base panel class that adds the buttons and each extending class then implements the different functionality or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a composite widget BottomToolbar consisting of a panel with two buttons. Add two methods to this widget: `setLeftButtonHandler(ClickHandler handler)` and `setRightButtonHandler(ClickHandler handler)`.

When you add this widget to the view, your Controller/Activity/Presenter (whatever you use) only needs to set these handlers.

Answer (score 0):

The best to do is to create one view that takes a controller which is different for your 4 or 5 views.

This is a basic MVC pattern : your view can be instanced several times but user can interact differently depending on the controller you give to the view.

Then, you can also extends your main view to provide more ui differences.